# Sencha Touch - HasOne Setter doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

So I have something along the lines of:

```
events: [
 {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Birthday Party',
    organiser: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jill'
    },
    attendees: [
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Bob'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Jill'
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

As usual: Events have a name, it has attendees but I'm also looking at having one organiser.

So I've setup my HasOne proxy within the Event to HasOne Organiser and I'm trying to create the Organiser object and attach it to the Event within the console but am having no luck.

I tried something like this, as the documentation says there should be a setter created... although only seems to give example for setting an ID (which also doesn't work).

```
var event = Ext.create('App.model.Event', {id: 1, name: 'Birthday Party'});
event.getOrganiser(); // says undefined

event.setOrganiser({
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jill'
}); // says TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get'

event.setOrganiser(1); // As the example but it still says the TypeError message

event.setOrganiser(Ext.create('App.model.Organiser', {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jill'
}); // says TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get'
```

So I'm confused... examples from Doc don't seem to be working for me but I need to pass in the rest of the data anyway. No idea how to approach this without spending an entire day going into the source code, dumping and breakpointing everything.

Any ideas? Should I be able to do any of the above or is it not meant to work that way? I want to POST both the Event and the Organiser object with one call... so was expecting JSON like this when I do event.save();

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Birthday Party',
    organiser: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jill'
    }
}
```

Sorry if you've seen this on the ST forum but it seems to be a ghost town

Thanks for any pointers or help :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated to ST 2.0.1.1 and this is what worked:

```
event.setOrganiser(Ext.create('App.model.Organiser', {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jill'
});
```